# improve a SELECT SQL query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

My data scheme is really simple, let s say it's about farms

- tableA is the main one, with an
  important field "is_active" assuming
  the farm is trusted (kind of)
- tableB    is a data storage of
  serialized    arrays about farms
  statistics

I want to retrieve all data about active farm so I just do something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON id_tableA=id_tableB WHERE is_active=1 ORDER BY id_tableA DESC;
```

Right now the query takes 15 sec to execute straight from a sql shell, for example it I want to retrieve all data from the tableB, like :

```
 SELECT * FROM tableB ORDER BY id_tableB DESC;
```

it takes less than 1 sec (approx 1200 rows)...

Any ideas how to improve the original query ?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create indexes on the keys joing two tables..

check this link, how to create indexes in mysql:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create an index.

You could create the following index:

> mysql> create index ix_a_active_id on tableA (id_tableA, is_active);
>
> mysql> create index ix_b_id on tableB (id_tableB);

This first creates an index on BOTH the id + is active variable.
The second creates an index on the id for tableB.

Comment: is there a mysql command than can show if I already have a index on the primary key or another field ? does it appears on a describe table ?